# client side improvement for python server

Tags: python, client, cgi, client-server

I'd appreciate some advice about the best strategy to use to improve a very basic server I've made.  At present I have an HTML front page which allows users to upload data to the server (it uses python's CGI module), data is processed by a python CGI script and the results are written to a shared area which the user can load into e.g. excel.  It's proving very popular and I'd like to improve things so that the client-side software (i.e. Excel) is automatically fired up and loads the results but this goes beyond my current knowledge, particularly on the client-side.

I'd be grateful for pointers to the book chapters/code snippets/web pages that show how this is done as.  All the numbercrunching needs to be done on the server as it will be very inefficient otherwise and I would like to stick with python on the server.  My main issue is that all the information I currently pass back to the client from the server (i.e. the name of the output file) is "dead" and is just text on the HTML page.  What I want to do now demands the client to do something in response which is altogether different.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the users to open your data directly into Excel, you could give them a static link to a page with .csv data (which is still just dead text on a page). At that point, the users could just open that URL [directly in Excel](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/open-web-pages-in-excel/639).

Probably a better solution is to provide the file (in a .csv or other common format) so that it can be downloaded directly, at which point they can open it in whatever tool they want (Excel, Stata, R). I'm not sure if that's what you're doing, or if you're requiring users to copy and paste the data.

Having some application like Excel open "automatically" on the client side is very messy even in the rare cases where it is possible, and furthermore there is absolutely no reason for it. Why force your users to use a particular application? What if they don't have that application? There is nothing wrong with having your users download the data and open it as they please.